# Abstract parameters and methods beginner

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstraction

I'm just doing some practice for my coding course. I've just started with abstraction so it's still a bit coonfusing for me. I've got this code and I've managed to assign values to the regular properties so far. I want to run an abstract property through a virtual method and have the result assigned to the property finally. The abstract method should be overridden on the second derived class but not the first.

Right now the result is that the BPM property has a value of 0 for both derived classes, though I'm not sure why.

```
public abstract class Music
{
    protected string genre;
    protected int bpm;

    public string Genre //property
    {
        get
        {
            return genre;
        }
        set
        {
            genre = value;
        }
    }

    public int Bpm //abstract property
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual int BPM(int b) //virtual method
    {
        this.bpm = b;
        return b;
    }

    public Music(string genre, int bpm)
    {
        this.genre = genre;
        this.bpm = BPM(bpm);
    }
}

public class Techno : Music
{
    public Techno(string genre, int bpm) : base(genre, bpm) { }
}

public class Dubstep : Music
{
    public override int BPM(int b)
    {
        return base.BPM(b) / 2;
    }

    public Dubstep(string genre, int bpm) : base(genre,bpm) { }
}

//PROGRAM-------------------------------------------------------------

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Techno t = new Techno("Techno", 130);
        Dubstep d = new Dubstep("Dubstep", 140);

        Console.WriteLine(t.Genre + " " + d.Genre);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Bpm + " " + d.Bpm);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Bpm` is not an abstract property (it isn't declared `abstract`); it's a regular property in an abstract class.

Comment: And `protected int bpm;` isn't related to `public int Bpm { get; set; }` aside from having similar names.

Comment: @Llama Oh! Ok I see. So then I guess the way I reference the property in the derived classes would also have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### Original Answer

First of all, this:

```
    public int Bpm //abstract property
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Is not an abstract property. What you are looking at here is an [Auto-implemented property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). That is a property for which the compiler creates a hidden backing field.

---

Second, here:

```
Console.WriteLine(t.Bpm + " " + d.Bpm);
```

You use the property mentioned above… *And nowhere else.* It is never assigned, so it has its default value, which happens to be 0.

---

You see, you have a field `protected int bpm;` that you use in your method:

```
    public virtual int BPM(int b) //virtual method
    {
        this.bpm = b;
        return b;
    }
```

You also set it in the constructor:

```
    public Music(string genre, int bpm)
    {
        this.genre = genre;
        this.bpm = BPM(bpm);
    }
```

But that field has nothing to do with the aforementioned property.

---

To reiterate `bpm` and `Bpm` are unrelated. *I suppose I should also mention that C# is case sensitive.*

---

### Extended answer

> So how would I make 'Bpm' and 'bpm' match, like 'Genre' and 'genre' match?

You have implemented the `Genre` property with a backing field `genre`:

```
    public string Genre //property
    {
        get
        {
            return genre;
        }
        set
        {
            genre = value;
        }
    }
```

This is similar to what the compiler does for `Bpm`. The only difference is that you don't get to access the `Bpm` backing field.

---

I'll throw you a curve ball, and say that you can implement `Genre` the way you implemented `Bpm` and it would work. This is what you would do:

- Remove the backing field `genre`.
- Make `Genre` auto-implemented: `public string Genre { get; set; }`.
- Have the constructor set the property `Genre = genre;`.

*As a result, you will see that your code is simpler and shorter. That is the point of auto-implemented properties.*

So, no, being an auto-implemented property is not preventing `Bpm` to work. The problem is that you are using a field `bpm` that has nothing to do with it.

Instead of writing to the unrelated field, you can write to the property from your constructor, for example:

```
    public Music(string genre, int bpm)
    {
        Genre = genre; // Set Genre property
        Bpm = bpm; // Set Bpm property
    }
```

---

> I want to run an abstract property through a virtual method and have the result assigned to the property finally

If I understand correctly, you expect `Dubstep d = new Dubstep("Dubstep", 140);` to have `Bpm` with the value `80`. Right?

So, we want all writes to pass through the method. This is how you do that:

```
public abstract class Music
{
    private int bpm;

    public Music(string genre, int bpm)
    {
        Genre = genre;
        Bpm = bpm;
    }

    public int Bpm
    {
        get => bpm;
        set => bpm = BPM(value);
    }

    public string Genre { get; set; }

    public virtual int BPM(int b) //virtual method
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Here, `Bpm` is no longer auto-implemented. It will read and write the field `pbm`.

*Also, Genre is auto-implemented. I made it so because we don't need to do anything special with it.*

Now, every time the property is set, this will run `bpm = BPM(value)`. Which will call the virtual method, which `Dubstep` overrides, resulting in the desired behavior.

---

To be clear, this code:

```
    public int Bpm
    {
        get => bpm;
        set => bpm = BPM(value);
    }
```

Is the same as this code:

```
    public int Bpm
    {
        get
        {
            return bpm;
        }
        set
        {
            bpm = BPM(value);
        }
    }
```

It is just a short-hand to write less code… *Which bites me in the back, because I got to explain it*. See [Expression-bodied members (C# programming guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members). Don't let the syntax confuse you.

Comment: Thank you that helps! So how would I make `Bpm` and `bpm` match, like `Genre` and `genre` match? Or does it work differently with regular properties and abstract properties?

Comment: @Mike see extended answer.

Comment: wow thank you for this! I was going over class notes all day yesterday trying to figure this out :)